# Find and delete directories older than time?

Tags: linux

I have a command which I am using to find and delete files within a directory older than a specified time. The command is:

```
sudo find /path/to/dir/* -daystart -mtime +7 -delete
```

How can I modify this command to delete directories as well as files within the specified directory.

Answer (score 6):

You probably don't want to remove directories based on their modification time. What you probably want to do is remove a directory once it has no files left in it.
One way to solve this would be the following:

```
find /path/to/dir -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

If you have directories which are frequently used, but sometimes empty, you could change the command to

```
find /path/to/dir -type d -empty -daystart -mtime +7 -exec rmdir {} \;
```

This will only remove the directory if it doesn't match the modification time criteria, as well as it being empty.

Answer (score 1):

This is the command I run to delete files:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

The following is untested, but I'm sure you could modify it to delete directories by doing something like this recursive delete:

```
find /path/to/dir -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: The second command is **VERY BAD**. Modification time of directories does not change when the contents of a file in the directory is modified, only when files are added or removed from the directory. Thus your second command will end up wiping out directories that shouldn't be.

Comment: Ah, true. Good point.

Comment: This is true however in this case I the directories are being created at the time of the files so this command will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
find $DNLD_DIR/* -mtime +7 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

removes directory without checking for empty or not. I use it for removing directories that I created with directory name as yyyymmdd and i know i want everything in it be cleaned up including directory.

Be very careful using this, though.  Any time you run `find | xargs rm -rf` you can ruin your day if the `find` conditions are wrong.